# Can QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() be used outside a GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, filedialog

I am experiencing a weird behavior from this simple line of code, which I wanted to use outside a pyqt GUI class

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

FilePath=QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,'choose the file')
```

When I first implemented it, it worked (probably because I run some other code before that I cannot trace back).

Then after restarting python, it stopped working and it crashes saying:

> QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

The same exact code works fine when implemented in a GUI, where the first argument is of course `self`.

But I would like to use the same filedialog in an external function I use for a different purpose, outside a GUI context.

Is it possible and what could be a way/workaround to implement that ? I would like to avoid using wx, easygui or tk

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the Qt UI elements (such as `QFileDialog`), you generally have to have a `QApplication` running. It seems a little unorthodox, but you can get your snippet to run just by instantiating a `QApplication` prior to your `QFileDialog`, like so

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
FilePath=QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,'choose the file')
```

Technically, this will work, though I'm not quite sure I can endorse doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion JCV, I already tried it. This solution works on itself, but as soon as I add some more code it crashes badly..

Answer (score 1):

Qt applications are built around an event loop and require QApplication instance. Dialogs have their own event loop, so if all you want is a wizard (a series of dialogs that open/close in sequence), then in principle all you need is the QApplication instance. The following works in PyQt 5:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
app = Qt.QApplication([])
FilePath=Qt.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,'choose the file')
print(FilePath)
```

However, if you have other code that assumes an application event loop, all bets are off. In that case, you could do the following:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt
app = Qt.QApplication([])
FilePath=Qt.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,'choose the file')
print(FilePath)
...create widgets....
QTimer.singleShot(someWidgetMethod)
app.exec_()
```

The single-shot timer will fire only during the `app.exec_()`, thus calling some of your code as part of the event loop.

All that being said,it is much better to create a main window and connect slots to signals and call `app.exec_()`. There are many examples included with PyQt, check those.